# Weak convergence, $L^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question about weak convergence.

Let $(S,\Sigma,m)$ be a measure space. $(f_{t})_{t>0}$ be a family of square integrable functions. (i.e. for every $t>0$, $f_{t} \in L^{2}(S;m)$) and $f$
 be a square integrable function.

**Question**

Let $(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with each $t_{n}>0$ and $t_{n} \searrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$. **I know the definition $f_{t_{n}} \to f$ weakly in $L^{2}(S;m)$.** **$f_{t_{n}} \to f$ weakly in $L^{2}(S;m)$** means
\begin{align*}
\forall g \in L^{2}(S;m),\int_{S}f_{t_{n}}gdm \to \int_{S} fg dm\quad{\rm as\,}n\to\infty
\end{align*}
**But I don't know $f_{t} \to f$ weakly in $L^{2}(S;m)$ as $t \searrow 0$**. What is the definition of this?

**My opinion**

I guess $f_{t} \to f$ weakly in $L^{2}(S;m)$ as $t \searrow 0$ means that
 **for every** sequence $(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with each $t_{n}>0$ and $t_{n} \searrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$, $f_{t_{n}} \to f$ weakly in $L^{2}(S;m)$.
 I'm wondering what you think about that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can say it thus. You can also say that $f_t \to f$ weakly as $t \searrow 0$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and $g \in L^2$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert \langle f_t - f, g\rangle\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $t < \delta$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood.